# Scala Slick Class Table Definition, Error Declaring DateTime columns

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Below is the DB Class
I have compilation errors on Datetime columns when making table definitions.

1. Created_on should be on update currrent date
2. updated_on should just emulate the passed on date.

   package tables

   ```
    import play.data.format.Formats.DateTime
    import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._


    object Main {

       case class Account(
                      id: Long = 0L,
                      owner: Long,
                      name: String,
                      created_on: DateTime,
                      updated_on: DateTime,
                      author_id: Long,
                      updated_by: Long,
                      external_id: String

                    )
   ```

   class AccountTable(tag: Tag) extends TableAccount {

   ```
   def id  = column[Long]("id")
    def owner= column[Long]("id")
    def name= column[String]("name")
    def created_on= column[DateTime]("created_on")
    def updated_on= column[DateTime]("updated_on")
    def author_id= column[Long]("author_id")
    def updated_by= column[Long]("updated_by")
    def external_id= column[String]("external_id")


    def * = (owner, name, created_on, 
      updated_on,author_id,updated_by,external_id) <> (Account.tupled, 
      Account.unapply)
   ```

   }

   }

Comment: Slick supports JDBC-based `java.sql.{Date, Time, Timestamp}`.  `Timestamp` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you also show the compilation error you're seeing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `DateTime` class you're using. Perhaps the Joda-time `DateTime` class?

For this, you need to provide a mapping from `DateTime` to a type the Slick knows about (and one that makes sense for the column in the database). For example, you could map `DateTime` to a `Timestamp`:

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC

// And in your `Main`...

implicit val jodaDateTimeType =
    MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
      dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
      ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime, UTC)
    )
```

...for example. This is teaching Slick how to convert from `DateTime` to a type it knows about (`Timestamp`).

There's a tutorial on this that goes into more details in [Chapter 5 of *Essential Slick*](https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#custom-column-mappings).

Since Slick 3.3, there's built-in support for many of the standard Java time formats, [described in the release notes](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/upgrade.html#support-for-java.time-columns).

Also, since Slick 3 you can map classes using `.mapTo` for most cases. It's much nicer to read than `<>`:

```scala
def * = (
  owner, name, created_on, updated_on, author_id, updated_by, external_id
).mapTo[Account]
```

Comment: Man thanks, It worked. more so when I followed the slick documentation